# Login de React js y Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, login

agradeceria su ayuda para crear un login usando firebase y reactjs, si hay alguna libreria y si se puede conectar por correo y contraseña.
saludos...
Cuento con este codigo en auth.jsx, pero tengo un error en el metodo flecha, no se como solucionarlo, en app.js solo se manda a implementar. Gracias!

```
import React, {useState} from  'react';
import 'firebase/auth';
import { useFirebaseApp } from 'reactfire';

export default (props)=> {
    const [email, setemail]= useState('');
    const [password, setpasword] = useState('');

    const firebase = useFirebaseApp(),

    const submit = async ()=> {
        await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);

    }

    return(
        <div align="center">
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="email">Correo electronico</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" onChange={ (ev)=> setemail(ev.target.value)}></input> <br/>
                <label htmlFor="password">Contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" onChange = {(ev)=> setpasword(ev.target.value)}></input> <br/>
                <br/>
                <button onClick = {submit}>Acceder por Correo</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir tu error?

Comment: Claro que si... Failed to compile
./src/Auth.jsx
  Line 11:5:  Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'const'

   9 |     const firebase = useFirebaseApp(),
  10 | 
> 11 |     const submit = async ()=> {
     |     ^
  12 |         const newLocal = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  13 | 
  14 |     }

Comment: Te equivocaste y pusiste una coma en vez de punto y coma. ```const firebase = useFirebaseApp(),``` debería de ser ```const firebase = useFirebaseApp();```

Comment: Ala gracias si termino todo lo que quiero intentaré subir el repositorio